# Having trouble locating memory leak in Perl

Tags: perl, memory-leaks, xml-parsing, strawberry-perl

I'm experiencing a memory leak (I think) in this snippet of code:

```
if (ref($init{'time-layout'}) eq 'HASH') {
    my %time= % {$init{'time-layout'}};
    my @times= @ {$time{'start-valid-time'}};
    if (ref($init{parameters}) eq 'HASH') {
        %param= % {$init{parameters}};
        if (ref($param{'wind-speed'}) eq 'HASH') {
            %wind= % {$param{'wind-speed'}};
            @windvalue= @ {$wind{value}};
            %temp= % {$param{'temperature'}};
            @tempvalue = @ {$temp{value}};
            %wdir= % {$param{'direction'}};
            @wdirvalue = @ {$wdir{value}};
            %hum= % {$param{'humidity'}};
            @humvalue = @ {$hum{value}};
        undef %wind;
        undef %temp;
        undef %wdir;
        undef %hum;}
    undef %param;}
```

This is from a sub, where the input comes from [XMLin()](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm#XMLin%28%29) (from [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm)).  Specifically the input is (if it matters)

```
http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdXMLclient.php?    lat=$lat&lon=$lon&product=time-series&begin=2004-01-01T00:00:00&end=2013-04-20T00:00:00&temp=temp&wspd=wspd&rh=rh&wdir=wdir";
```

where `$lat` and `$lon` are latitude and longitude.

The code takes a couple hours, to run plugging data into a SQL server, and well before it's done the instance of Perl is taking several GBs of RAM or more.  I'm sure this is simple for someone but I'm, at best, a novice in Perl.

Comment: If you are not making changes to data that you want to keep read-only, don't make copies of it, e.g. just say `@windvalue = @{$init{parameters}->{'wind-speed'}->{value}}`.

Comment: @imran I made those changes and it may have appeared to help a bit but the other answers about XML::Simple being the problem appear to be correct.

Comment: What is the version of Perl you are using?

Comment: @Drt I'm running Strawberry Perl 5.16.2

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I would recommend using XML::LibXML::Reader module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick duckduckgo search for "xml::simple memory leak" turned up the documentation for Yahoo::Search, which claims:

> XML::Simple uses XML::Parser under the hood, and at least on the
>   systems I've tested it, XML::Parser suffers from a crippling memory
>   leak that makes it very undesirable.

It appears possible (perhaps even likely) that the memory leak may not be in your code at all.

Comment: I believe it was both because I carried out imran's suggestion which helped a little and I was just finding that my RAM usage was going up each time I pass over my XMLin command.  Is this the problem to which you were refering? http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=251630  I hope not its 10 years old.

Answer (score 3):

`XML::Simple` is very ineffective on **parsing large files** (for me it eats *3Gb of memory for the 100Mb file*). Try to `use XML::Twig` for your data.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [imran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319296/imran)'s comment,

With so many XML cpan modules, it is very hard to decide which one should be used.

Looking at answers from many and reading from web, [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0014/LibXML.pod) looks a preferred module, rather more specific [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://search.cpan.org/~pajas/XML-LibXML-1.70/lib/XML/LibXML/Reader.pod) for large files. Many of them haven't recommended using `XML::Simple` and says `XML::Simple` is good for small files and have issues when it comes to large xml files. `XML::Twig` is better(from it's documentation), but even that is having memory leak problems also. (refer [XML::Twig faq](http://www.xmltwig.org/xmltwig/XML-Twig-FAQ.html))

You wanna also refer [perl-xml-faq](http://perl-xml.sourceforge.net/faq/)